# cherrypy SessionAuth not working?

Tags: python, cherrypy

I'm probably overlooking something simple, but I cannot get Cherrypy SessionAuth to work.

With debug on and no username in cherrypy.session, SessionAuth puts this in the log file:

```
[20/Feb/2013:00:58:39] TOOLS.SESSAUTH No username, routing to login_screen with from_page 'http://localhost:8080/'
```

The trouble is it doesn't route to the login screen.  It returns true to the caller and the caller continues to execute.  It also sets cherrypy.serving.response.body to a snippet of html that renders to a login page.  But my calling function knows nothing about response.body.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the relevant code from root.py:

```
class MySessionAuth(cptools.SessionAuth):

    def check_username_and_password(self, username, password):
        users = dict(foo="bar")
        if username in users and password == users[username]:
            return False

    def on_check(self, username):
        cherrypy.session['username'] = username


def session_auth(**kwargs):
    sa = MySessionAuth()
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        setattr(sa, k, v)
    return sa.run()

cherrypy.tools.protect = cherrypy._cptools.Tool('before_handler', session_auth)


class Root:
    @cherrypy.expose()
    @cherrypy.tools.protect(debug=True)
    def index(self):
        tmpl = loader.load('index.html')
        return tmpl.generate(flash = '',).render('html', doctype='html')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to protect the entire application by password and not just certain resources you can create a custom function for check_username_and_password and in your application configuration have the check_username_and_password point to it.
The config line to add  would like something like this

```
'tools.session_auth.check_username_and_password':check_username_and_password
```

Then just use your custom check_username_and_password that you have above and it should work.

Here is a full example that will protect all resources in an application

```
import cherrypy
from datetime import datetime

user_dict={'peter':'password','joe':'pass1234','tom':'!Sm,23&$fiuD'}
def check_user(username,password):
     if user_dict.has_key(username):
          if user_dict[username] == password:
               return
          else:
               return 'incorrect password for user'
     return 'user does not exist'

class Root:
     @cherrypy.expose
     def index(self):
          cherrypy.session.regenerate()
          cherrypy.session['access_datetime'] = datetime.now()
          return """Hello protected resource! <br \>
datetime of access was %s
<br /><a href="./logout">Logout</a>"""%cherrypy.session['access_datetime']


     @cherrypy.expose
     def logout(self):
          username = cherrypy.session['username']
          cherrypy.session.clear()
          return """%s you have been logged out
of the system at datetime %s"""%(username,datetime.now())

_cp_config={'/':{'tools.sessions.on':True,
                'tools.sessions.storage_type':'file',
                'tools.sessions.storage_path':'./',
                'tools.sessions.timeout':60,
                'tools.session_auth.on':True,
                'tools.session_auth.check_username_and_password':check_user,
                 }
            }
cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host':'0.0.0.0',
                        'server.socket_port':8090})
cherrypy.quickstart(Root(),'/',config=_cp_config)
```